# What KeyConditionExpression on DynamoDb for "Query all items" when using LeadingKeys condition in IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm writing an integration request in API Gateway, which should query a DynamoDb table. I'm using a specific role to access the database, leveraging the [fine-grained access control mechanism](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html), and I have no idea which KeyConditionExpression to use.

I would like to "query for all items", and let DynamoDb take care of which ones to return based on the LeadingKeys of my IAM policy.

So far I tried a simple:

```
{"ProjectionExpression": "sortKey", "ConsistentRead": false, "TableName": "testTable"}
```

But this predictably fails with:

> {   "__type": "com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException",
>   "message": "Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression
>   parameter must be specified in the request." }

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it on my own.
You simply can't send a Query without specifying a partition key, but you can define a dynamic partition key.

You can use API Gateway context variables to pass a KeyProjectionExpression that will match your policy's LeadingKeys. In my case, it was Cognito Identity:

```
{
"KeyConditionExpression":"pk=:pk", 
"ExpressionAttributeValues":{":pk":{"S":"$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId"}}
}
```

A more complete list of API Gateway variables is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html).